Crystal Report is loading but not displaying any data
I implemented code to load the Crystal Report using a Web API call in my Windows Forms application.
Below is my report load event. fromDate, toDate, profileId are the user input parameters to execute the stored procedure. When I run the code, the GetIWD0001Data method returns the correct data and passes the data to the datasource as well. But report loads without the data (empty report load).
private void frmIWDReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        oCRDoc.Load(fileFullPath);

        switch (reportName)
        {
            case "IWD0001.rpt":
                IWD0001 IWD0001 = GetIWD0001Data(fromDate, toDate, profileId);
                oCRDoc.SetDataSource(IWD0001);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        crystalViewer.ReportSource = oCRDoc;
        Refresh();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        DMSLogger.Write(ex);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}

public IWD0001 GetIWD0001Data(int product, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int profileId)
{
    IWD0001 dataSet = new IWD0001();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(IMAGO.Common.Portal.Switcher.GetConnectionString(product)))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Call the first stored procedure: IMAGO_RPT_IRD_IRDCHQ
            using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("IMAGO_RPT_IRD_IRDCHQ", connection))
            {
                command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FROM", fromDate));
                command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TO", toDate));

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command1))
                {
                    adapter1.Fill(dataSet, "IMAGO_RPT_IRD_IRDCHQ");
                }
            }

            // Call the second stored procedure: IMAGO_RPT_GET_BRANCHES
            using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("IMAGO_RPT_GET_BRANCHES", connection))
            {
                command2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROFILE_ID", profileId));

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(command2))
                {
                    adapter2.Fill(dataSet, "IMAGO_RPT_GET_BRANCHES");
                }
            }

            // Query for MSYSTEMSETTING table
            string sqlQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM MSYSTEMSETTING";

            using (SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery2, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(command3))
                {
                    adapter2.Fill(dataSet, "MSYSTEMSETTING");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DMSLogger.Write(ex);
        throw; // Ensure the exception is re-thrown or handled as necessary
    }

    return dataSet;
}


Not sure about this specific issue, but in general I try to avoid naming variables the same as their type.
Maybe try changing the lines from frmIWDReportViewer_Load from
IWD0001 IWD0001 = GetIWD0001Data(fromDate, toDate, profileId); 
oCRDoc.SetDataSource(IWD0001);

to
IWD0001 IWD0001A = GetIWD0001Data(fromDate, toDate, profileId); 
oCRDoc.SetDataSource(IWD0001A);

If that doesn't work, then maybe try a different, minimalist dataset to ensure its not a data error problem.  I have seen bad data generate issues away from the current code so it won't be caught by your try block.  What happens is there is just no data returned.
